# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding'

Tags: cryptography, python-3.8, flask-user

I have installed the package `cryptography` using pip in order to use the `UserManager` class from `Flask-User`. However, when running my code I get the following error:

```
File "c:\Users\env\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\padding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding
```

How can I solve this error? When looking in the 'site-packages' folder of my virtual environment, I see that the file it wants to import is called `_padding-cp38-win32.pyd` instead of just `_padding`. Does this matter? Can someone please help me?

I am using Python v3.8.6, Flask-User v1.0.2.2, and Cryptography v3.2.1.